# Tuple projections in OCaml interface for Z3

Tags: ocaml, z3

I am trying to create formulas in which I reference specific elements of a tuple in the OCaml Interface for Z3. Is there some way to express the projection of a tuple in the interface?

In general, I have been trying to find more resources on the OCaml interface but have only found this:
https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/index.html,
which contains minimal descriptions, and this example:
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/ml/ml_example.ml

Are there any other resources/examples that can assist me with the interface?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think the function you're looking for is `get_field_decls`, which will return `n` functions for each element of the n-ary tuple. You're correct that the documentation is minimal, without many resources to turn to. Give `get_field_decls` a try, and post if you have problems using it. Tangentially, if you're new to z3, I'd very much recommend using a different API, unless you have to use O'Caml for some other reason. You'll find more help with the Python API for instance, and there are other APIs (in Haskell for instance) that provide an easier-to-use experience in my personal opinion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

I'd love to be able to use a different API since I'm new to z3, but I'm tied to using OCaml unfortunately.